# Lodash for Python?

Tags: python, lodash

Is there a library or something similar to lodash, for Python? We use the library extensively on our API and while we move on to creating a series of Python workers, it would make sense to create a similar structure to our API syntactics.

Comment: In what ways would using a library improve your workflow with Arrays, Lists, Sets, and Dicts that using generators, comprehensions, functools (map, filter, reduce, etc), and lambdas leave off?  I understand wanting a tool that acts similarly to something you already use, but the functionality is already there with Python when you use it to its fullest. While both of the modules linked so far (pytoolz & pydash) cover emulation of lodash/underscore they're really just window dressing on basic python functionality; it would be better to understand the language than retrofit on something you know.

Comment: I agree, but we are simply allowing our NodeJS team an easier entrance into our Python projects. It's much easier for a Python dev to understand what these libraries do than a NodeJS dev to learn Python. I was hoping to bridge that gap and shorten the learning curve. As with most developers, at some point the curiosity will take hold and our NodeJS devs will likely want to understand what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: here is an example:  _.get(w, 'x.y.z')
in python if you do w.x.y.z you will throw an exception if w, x, or y are null.  with _.get you will just get back a null instead

Comment: @JeffLangemeier I don't agree. The pydash (and lodash) provides helper functions that are the most needed/used by developers. It is true that some of them are very easy to be written in plain Python, but plenty of them aren't. And if you are in a position: use pydash vs write helper function yourself, then you should consider that pydash function is already tested, optimized and compatible with Python2.7&3, not mentioning it is already written. At my work I need to meet all the above criteria and using pydash/lodash saves me a lot of time. As a bonus I read pydash code to improve my python.

Comment: @m4js7er Since you're willing to necro my response from a year back; would you also be willing to provide concrete examples of "hard to optimize" lambda/functional programming paradigms that are provided via pydash?  My point still stands, JS and Python are different languages, with different paradigms and different applications... to take something from JS and try to wholesale port it to Python may give the user unintended results due to differences in the language.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[pydash](https://github.com/dgilland/pydash) is exactly like lodash, only for Python.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Just be aware that pydash has a *very poor performance* with some methods, for example pydash.arrays.uniq, if you have a big array with objects. I have already had problems with this.

Answer (score 8):

[pydash](https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) is something which you can use as a replacement of lodash in python. Almost everything is covered under it, the names of functions are also similar just keeping python's conventions as is.

**Important:** I've been using *pydash* for around 07 months, It helped me a lot. One thing which you should not forget is, avoid using pydash functions directly on *self*, its behaviour is very erratic and gives random results. I'm showing one example below.

**Sample Class**

```
class MyClass:
    def get(self):
       self.obj = {}
       self.obj['a'] = True
```

**Usage**
    class TestClass:
       def **init**(self):
          self.inst = MyClass()

```
   def test_function(self):
      # **Not Recommended Method**
      # _.get(self, "inst.a")    # shows random behavior

      # **Highly recommended**
      _.get(self.inst, "a")     # Will always return True
```

Comment: Using `_` is not a good idea. Please change it to some other variable name like `py_` shown one in pydash documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but when I think of javascript libraries like underscore and Lodash, I think of libraries that add more functional programming functions(though I do believe both underscore and lodash have a little more utility than that) to a language.

There are a bunch of Python Libraries that try and add some of the same functionality. A quick search got me pytoolz https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz which I don't have much experience with but looks interesting. If that isn't what you're looking for, try searching for other functional programming python libraries until you find one you like.

Hope that helped

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I guess what I am really after is something to ease working with Arrays, Dictionaries and types.