# Go from a string describing nested attributes (dot syntax) to accessing these nested attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I want to modify parameters that contain nested properties that need to be modified in the following way :

```
parameters.foo.bar.set(newvalue)
```

I have dozens of values that I want to access this way.

how can I create a function that does the following without eval :

```
def change_params(dict_new_values):
    global parameters
    for key,val in dict_new_values.items():
        eval("parameters."+key+".set(val)")
```

My problem is that eval is arguably unsafe, since the values of the dictionary come from external sources.

My current workaround is to check one by one all the values that path_parameter could have, but it is really inconvenient to have to update the list of possible values.  It it the only way I could convince my coworkers that I can use the eval safely, but the eval still makes the code hard to read and maintain :

```
list_possible_values=set(["foo.bar","foo.boz","otherparamname","yetanother.path"])
def change_params(dict_new_values):
    global parameters
    for key,val in dict_new_values.items():
        if key in list_possible_values:
            eval("parameters."+key+".set(val)")
```

For those who know JavaScript, I'm looking for the equivalent in python 3 of `lodash.get` and `lodash.set` that would enable this.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

Comment: Maybe the question [Lodash for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35317777/4996248) might help.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
getattr(parameters, key).set(val)
```

if you need attributes of attributes, I suppose you could do this:

```
attrs = key.split(".")
getattr(attrs[1], getattr(parameters, attrs[0])).set(val)
```

note however that getters and setters are unpythonic, and you should use [properties](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) instead.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work when I describe a path within an attribute : getattr(myobject,"foo.bar") returns an error object has no attribute "foo.bar"  while when I call  getattr(myobject.foo,"bar") it does work

Comment: @WNG I've updated the answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, although it only works in the case where my nested attributes are two. I see how I could extend it to more than 2 though, but I still have hope for an even more elegant solution even if the getattr is already helpful.